# UDP Checksum Function in Perl

Tags: c, perl

I have searched much i need function to calculate UDP header checksum in Perl.

I find this function in C: http://www.netfor2.com/udpsum.htm
But i don't know how to use it and i try to convert it to Perl but not managed

This what i try:

```
sub udp_checksum(my $len_udp, my @src_addr, my @dest_addr, my $padding, my @buff)
{
    my $proto_udp = 17;
    my $padd = 0;
    my $word16;
    my $sum;

    # Find out if the length of data is even or odd number. If odd,
    # add a padding byte = 0 at the end of packet
    if ($padding&1==1){
        $padd = 1;
        $buff[$len_udp] = 0;
    }

    # initialize sum to zero
    $sum = 0;

    # make 16 bit words out of every two adjacent 8 bit words and 
    # calculate the sum of all 16 bit words
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $len_udp + $padd; $i = $i + 2){
        $word16 =(($buff[i] << 8) & 0xFF00) + ($buff[i+1] & 0xFF);
        $sum = $sum + $word16;
    }

    # add the UDP pseudo header which contains the IP source and destinationn addresses
    for (my $i = 0; $i < 4; $i = $i + 2){
        $word16 =(($src_addr[i] << 8) & 0xFF00) + ($src_addr[i+1] & 0xFF);
        $sum = $sum + $word16;
    }

    for (my $i = 0; $i < 4; $i = $i + 2){
        $word16 =(($dest_addr[i] << 8) & 0xFF00) + ($dest_addr[i+1] & 0xFF);
        $sum = $sum + $word16;
    }

    # the protocol number and the length of the UDP packet
    $sum = $sum + $prot_udp + $len_udp;

    # keep only the last 16 bits of the 32 bit calculated sum and add the carries
        while ($sum >> 16){
            $sum = ($sum & 0xFFFF) + ($sum >> 16);
        }

    # Take the one's complement of sum
    $sum = ~$sum;

    return $sum;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Right off the bat, `sub udp_checksum(my $len_udp, my @src_addr, my @dest_addr, my $padding, my @buff) { ... }` isn't Perl. That might actually be the only problem.

Comment: `return $sum;` should be `return $sum & 0xFFFF;`

Comment: Tip: `$sum = $sum + $word16;` can be written as `$sum += $word16;`

Comment: Already used ~ instead of using & mask. And about += good suggestion, I'am not right now review the style. I was try to convert this. So how can i make a sub function and pass arguments to it like in C? Can you also tell me how to use this function?

Comment: Re "*Already used ~ instead of using & mask.*", That make no sense. `return $sum;` should be `return $sum & 0xFFFF;`.

Comment: Re "*So how can i make a sub function and pass arguments to it like in C?*", Isn't that an easy question to answer yourself? Out of time here.

Comment: I don't get you but if i make this mask what difference? if for example it's 1010 1010 and you & it with 1111 1111 so it will be same 1010 1010...........................

Comment: `10101010 & 1111` isn't `10101010`, it's `1010`. /// In Perl, `~0x1234` gives `0xFFFFFB2D` (ivsize=4) or `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFB2D` (ivsize=8), but the function is suppose to return `0xFB2D`. In the C code you are translating, this is done using a type cast (`return (u16)sum;`). In the Perl version, you can use  `return $sum & 0xFFFF;`

Comment: Ok, I means & 1111 1111 anyway i really don't know much in Perl just i'am very starter. So i do what you said like: https://pastebin.com/w9Y99ExC but just to ask you my $src_addr, my $dest_addr, my $buff these when i give them value the value in Hex or binary?

Comment: Re "*Ok, I means & 1111 1111*", No, you had it right. The mask is smaller than the number. You are returning a 32-bit or 64-bit number when only the lowest 16-lowest bits should be returned, and that's done by replacing `$sum` with `$sum & 0xFFFF`.

Comment: Re "*but just to ask you my $src_addr, my $dest_addr, my $buff these when i give them value the value in Hex or binary?*", Hex and binary are *text* representations of numbers. Neither are what your code needs. Your code needs arrays of bytes for those. My answer instead requires strings of bytes because that's far more convenient for both `udp_checksum` and its caller.

Comment: In the C code, `if (padding&1==1)` should have been `if (len_udp&1==1)`.

Comment: In the C code, `buff[len_udp]=0;` could be a buffer overflow. This problem didn't carry over into your code, though.

Comment: That's ok i'll try your code better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use List::Util qw( sum );
use Socket     qw( IPPROTO_UDP );

sub udp_checksum {
    my $packed_src_addr = shift;  # As 4-char string, e.g. as returned by inet_aton.
    my $packed_dst_addr = shift;  # As 4-char string, e.g. as returned by inet_aton.
    my $udp_packet      = shift;  # UDP header and data as a string.

    my $sum = sum(
        IPPROTO_UDP,
        length($udp_packet),
        map({ unpack('n*', $_) }
            $packed_src_addr,
            $packed_dst_addr,
            $udp_packet."\0",  # Extra byte ignored if length($udp_packet) is even.
        ),
    );

    while (my $hi = $sum >> 16) {
        $sum = ($sum & 0xFFFF) + $hi;
    }

    return ~$sum & 0xFFFF;
}
```

To build a UDP packet,

```
my $udp_packet = pack('nnnna*', $src_port, $dst_port, 8+length($body), 0, $body);
my $checksum = udp_checksum($packed_src_addr, $packed_dst_addr, $udp_packet);
substr($udp_packet, 6, 2, pack('n', $checksum));
```

To verify a UDP packet's checksum,

```
udp_checksum($packed_src_addr, $packed_dst_addr, $udp_packet)
    and die("Invalid checksum\n");
```

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Socket;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(sum);
use Socket     qw(IPPROTO_UDP);
use Socket     qw(inet_aton);

main();

sub main {
    my $src_port = 27005;
    my $dst_port = 27015;
    my $body = pack("H*", "92380000621f008063d5179000927df3a2e09bf319a66bf300c239aa9393d8eaa244119a");
    my $packed_src_addr = inet_aton("156.215.205.76");
    my $packed_dst_addr = inet_aton("31.186.251.163");

    my $udp_packet = pack('nnnna*', $src_port, $dst_port, 8+length($body), 0, $body);
    my $checksum = udp_checksum($packed_src_addr, $packed_dst_addr, $udp_packet);

    print "\n\nUDP Checksum: $checksum\n\n";
}

sub udp_checksum {
    my $packed_src_addr = shift;  # As 4-char string, e.g. as returned by inet_aton.
     my $packed_dst_addr = shift;  # As 4-char string, e.g. as returned by inet_aton.
    my $udp_packet      = shift;  # UDP header and data as a string.

    my $sum = sum(
    IPPROTO_UDP,
    length($udp_packet),
    map({ unpack('n*', $_) }
        $packed_src_addr,
        $packed_dst_addr,
        $udp_packet."\0",  # Extra byte ignored if length($udp_packet) is even.
        ),
    );

    while (my $hi = $sum >> 16) {
        $sum = ($sum & 0xFFFF) + $hi;
    }

    return ~$sum & 0xFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Nice just what you mean by 4-char? Example: The source ip: 94.122.166.249 and the dest: 5.196.159.54 How i write them then?

Comment: `use Socket qw( inet_aton ); my $addr = inet_aton("94.122.166.249");` Also takes domain names. Alternatively, `my $addr = pack('C4', split(/\./, "94.122.166.249"));`

Comment: And udp header is src port, dest port, udp length and those are integers so how can i add them together? And data is in hex so if can you give me example? I use wireshark so i say this

Comment: `my $udp_packet = pack('nnnna*', $src_port, $dst_port, 8+length($body), 0, $body);`

Comment: And values like: `$src_port = 27005`
`$dst_port = 27015`
`$body = "\xf6\x12\x00\x00\x5d\x12\x00\x80\x63\x33\x10\xf4\x00\xf6\x50\xbd\x3a\x84\xb1\xbd\x19\x02\x4d\xbd\xb2\xa7\x13\x74\x5d"` ?

Comment: Yup! Added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Yes excellent now but the body should be in hex right? as i do or?

Comment: It shouldn't be hex. For example, `$body = "f61200...";` would place the hex representation of the body in `$body`, and that would be bad. What you did above was correct. You may have used hex in your code, but that has nothing to do with what's in `$body`.

Comment: Tip: `$body  = "\xf6\x12\x00...";` can be shortened to `$body  = pack("H*", "f61200...");`.

Comment: Ok let me test now and tell you. I'll see if the function will return the same checksum wireshark calculated or not

Comment: Great, The value in wireshark is: Checksum: 0x9915 and it's same result with this function. Big thanks for you.