# Sending spoofed syslog messages in Perl

Tags: perl, sockets

*TL;DR I am trying to send syslog messages I have already created to a syslog server using spoofed source IPs but I'm making it really hard for myself and could do with a succinct approach*

*Most questions about syslog do not include the spoofed IP problem hence I am asking afresh.*

I am writing (well updating) a script I wrote a long time ago that generates spoofed syslog messages (using UDP).  It currently uses Net::RawIP which is terrible for portability and also the code for the transmission I wrote ages ago has decided to stop working in Perl 5 (I haven't used this for ages and I am refreshing it).  I have been meaning to get rid of Net::RawIP for ages but its the only one I know how to use!

Given I have to fix it and I have a little time at the moment I probably want to move to use the Socket capability, which is what I have been playing with - using code from SO or gists or other places I can find - rather than something like IO::Socket as I need the spoofed IPs permission given a low level ability to write to sockets.

However, I have tied myself in knots with this, what I have right now forms the packets from scratch and then creates a socket and sends it, but in the processes wraps a superflous IPv4 header (I can see using wireshark) and without starting afresh I think its stuck like that as it has a fundamental flaw, hence I'm not sharing old code.

Basically, I can keep playing with the overly complicated code I have or ask for help simplify it, as I am beyond my knowledge of sockets and many hours of googling haven't helped much.  What I keep finding is code that will work but it not compliant in some way - probably not an issue for what they are usually for which is for DDOS or syn attacks or whatever.

Key requirements of this are (which every attempt I have done has failed in some form!):

- must come from a spoofed source IP and go to a known destination IP
  (hence I'm using UDP) (both of which I have in config variables) so that the syslog server things many different devices generated the logs
- must come from a set port and go to a set port (both of which I have in my
  existing config variables)
- must contain a message I have already formed which includes all the syslog content (the PRI and the syslog message content)
- must be fully complaint with checksums and packet lengths etc when received
- be as portable as possible (I'll probably embed it in my main script to keep it all in one file I can share  with others).

I just feel there must be a simple and easy way to do this as everything I have is overly flexible and complicated and a nightmare to unwind.

NB This is shared in Sourceforge as "must syslog" and so you can see what I used to do but be aware its stopped working so it wont work if you run it currently!  Once I fix this I'll upload a new version.

Cheers, --Chris

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to paste your code.

Comment: @daxim as per the text I'm not pasting code as its a horrendously complicated mess and I want to start from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just had a breakthrough, I have linked the sources in the code but I found a test harness that is pretty basic and some UDP checksum code that with a bit of playing worked together and wireshark confirms its all correct

Posted in case someone else needs it as its taken me a good couple of days to get to this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Socket;
use List::Util qw(sum);


sub udp_checksum {
    # thanks to ikegami in post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181281/udp-checksum-function-in-perl
    my $packed_src_addr = shift;  # As 4-char string, e.g. as returned by inet_aton.
     my $packed_dst_addr = shift;  # As 4-char string, e.g. as returned by inet_aton.
    my $udp_packet      = shift;  # UDP header and data as a string.

    my $sum = sum(
    IPPROTO_UDP,
    length($udp_packet),
    map({ unpack('n*', $_) }
        $packed_src_addr,
        $packed_dst_addr,
        $udp_packet."\0",  # Extra byte ignored if length($udp_packet) is even.
        ),
    );

    while (my $hi = $sum >> 16) {
        $sum = ($sum & 0xFFFF) + $hi;
    }

    return ~$sum & 0xFFFF;
}

#this was found and adapted from http://rhosted.blogspot.com/2009/08/creating-udp-packetip-spoofing-through.html

$src_host = $ARGV[0];
$dst_host = $ARGV[1];
$src_port = 33333;
$dest_port = 514;
$cksum = 0; #initialise, we will sort this later

#$udp_len is the udp packet length in the udp header. Its just 8 plus the length of the data
#for this test harness we will set the data here too
$data = "<132> %FWSM-3-106010: Deny inbound tcp src outside:215.251.218.222/11839 dst inside:192.168.1.1/369";
$udp_len = 8+length($data);

$udp_proto = 17; #17 is the code for udp


#Prepare the udp packet, needed for the checksum to happen, then get the checksum (horrifically complicated, just google it)
$udp_packet = pack("nnnna*", $src_port,$dest_port,$udp_len, $cksum, $data);
$cksum = udp_checksum(inet_aton($src_host),inet_aton($dst_host),$udp_packet);

$zero_cksum = 0; 

#test harness checks about host IPs
my $dst_host = (gethostbyname($dst_host))[4]; my $src_host = (gethostbyname($src_host))[4];

# Now lets construct the IP packet
my $ip_ver = 4;
my $ip_len = 5;
my $ip_ver_len = $ip_ver . $ip_len;
my $ip_tos = 00;
my ($ip_tot_len) = $udp_len + 20;
my $ip_frag_id = 19245;
my $ip_frag_flag = "010";
my $ip_frag_oset = "0000000000000";
my $ip_fl_fr = $ip_frag_flag . $ip_frag_oset;
my $ip_ttl = 30;

#H2H2nnB16C2na4a4 for the IP Header part#nnnna* for the UDP Header part.
#To understand these, see the manual of pack function and IP and UDP Header formats
#IP checksum ($zero_cksum is calculated by the kernel. Dont worry about it.)

my ($pkt) = pack('H2H2nnB16C2na4a4nnnna*',
$ip_ver_len,$ip_tos,$ip_tot_len,$ip_frag_id,
$ip_fl_fr,$ip_ttl,$udp_proto,$zero_cksum,$src_host,
$dst_host,$src_port,$dest_port,$udp_len, $cksum, $data);

#bit that makes the socket and sends the packet
socket(RAW, AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 255) || die $!; setsockopt(RAW, 0, 1, 1);
my ($destination) = pack('Sna4x8', AF_INET, $dest_port, $dst_host);
send(RAW,$pkt,0,$destination);
```